# apache2 password protected directory

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd, password

I password protected a part of my website.

How can I destroy the session of one user when I want to login with another user? Where can I change the time out of the session (if possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .htaccess to protect the directory?

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html

Quote:
"How do I log out?

Since browsers first started implementing basic authentication, website administrators have wanted to know how to let the user log out. Since the browser caches the username and password with the authentication realm, as described earlier in this tutorial, this is not a function of the server configuration, but is a question of getting the browser to forget the credential information, so that the next time the resource is requested, the username and password must be supplied again. There are numerous situations in which this is desirable, such as when using a browser in a public location, and not wishing to leave the browser logged in, so that the next person can get into your bank account.

However, although this is perhaps the most frequently asked question about basic authentication, thus far none of the major browser manufacturers have seen this as being a desirable feature to put into their products.

Consequently, the answer to this question is, you can't. Sorry."

Comment: is it also impossible from the user side ?
I am trying to test if all the usernames / password combinations work.

Comment: only by closing the browser and reopen it.

Comment: that will mean rebooting then. I tried closing the firefox window but after reopening the site did not ask for any credentials.

Comment: you need to close ALL firefox windows. Since the password credentials are stored only in session, means in temporary cache, it gets purged when closing all browser windows. A new session will then get started when reopening the browser.